# Grafana docker container status UP or Down

Tags: docker, containers, grafana, status

How to create Dashbosrd on Grafana that displays status of docker container UP or DOWN?
Example:
Name       Status
Container1 UP
Conteiner2 Down

Solution
The way of creation the dashboard with the name of docker container and status

Comment: Do you have cadvisor or any other scraper of docker metrics?

Answer (score 0):

I am using Cadvisor to collect Docker metrics and info.
Add cadvisor to your prometheus.yml

Then, I add this piece of code in prometheus.yml

```
  - job_name: "docker"
    docker_sd_configs:
      - host: "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
        refresh_interval: "1s"
    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: ['__meta_docker_container_name']
        target_label: "container_name"
      - source_labels: ['__meta_docker_container_id']
        target_label: "container_id"
```

After that, I can choose docker container name and select cadvisor metric in Grafana (prometheus datasource)

For example we can use this PromQL:

```
container_tasks_state{name=~".+.",state="running"}
```

This is how I do in my production environment, if you have any questions, I will glad to answer

Comment: Thank. But it is not yhe output that i want
I want that Grafana will display Containner1:Up, container2:Down